# Separate cron job for reindex all?

Tags: cron

I've set up the cron job for magento. Do I have to set up a separate cron job for reindex? I'm running Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do  this by can PHP script with include mage.php at that script

**Step1:** create `PHP file` and   include `mage.php at the head section of this PHP file and set store as an admin

```
require_once "yourmagneto instacedir/www/www/app/Mage.php";
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "admin" );
```

**Step2:** get Collection of indexes and try to reindex by  each index

```
  try {
        foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
                    /* @var $process Mage_Index_Model_Process */
                    $process = $indexer->getProcessById($index->getId());
                    if ($process) {
                        $process->reindexEverything();
                    }
                }
                $count = count($processIds);

                   $meassage.= 'Total of %d index(es) have reindexed data'.$count;

            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
               $meassage.= $e->getMessage();

         // $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
```

**Step3:** add this PHP file to cron job

Or

### you can do this by shell program

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

format

```
php indexer.php --reindex indexcode
```

**Default index code:**

Process Name  ->    ID  Code

**Product Prices** -> `catalog_product_price`

**Catalog URL Rewrites** -> `catalog_url`

**Product Flat Data** -> `catalog_product_flat`

**Category Flat Data**  -> `catalog_category_flat`

**Category Products**  -> `catalog_category_product`

**Catalog Search Index**  -> `catalogsearch_stock`

**Stock Status**  ->  `cataloginventory_stock`

**Tag Aggregation Data**  -> `tag_summary`

http://www.clounce.com/magento/magento-reindex-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a separate cron job, we have to build cron functionality in Magento.

Simply you need to set on the server.

*/5 * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null

http://www.yoursite.com/absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php

and add reindexing code bottom of cron job(cron.php) class.

// this loops through all indexes and processes those that say they require re-indexing

```
include_once '../app/Mage.php';

    $mageRunCode = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
    $mageRunType = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

        $app = Mage::app ( $mageRunCode, $mageRunType );
        for($i=3; $i<=9; $i++){
            $process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessById($i);
            $state = $process->getStatus();
        //    echo '<pre>'.$process->getData('indexer_code').': '.htmlentities(print_r($process->getStatus(),true)).'</pre>';
            if($process->getStatus() == 'require_reindex'){
                $process->reindexEverything();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To make separate & custom cron job for re-indexing follow below code/steps.

- Add cron job into `config.xml` as below.
- `<crontab>
      <jobs>
          <my_cronscript_custom_re_index>
              <schedule><cron_expr>30 0 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
              <run><model>MODULE_NAME/customreindex::runCustomReIndex</model></run>
          </my_cronscript_custom_re_index>
      </jobs>
  </crontab>`
- `30 0 * * *` this cron will run every mid-night
- Cron model file `Customreindex.php`
- `class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Customreindex {
     public function runCustomReIndex() {
         Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
         Mage::app()->cleanCache();

         $indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
         foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
             $index->reindexAll();
         }

    } 
  }`
- `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();` and `Mage::app()->cleanCache();` are to clear cache. You can avoid it if just need to re-index

Answer (score 1):

In short No, you don't need a separate cron task, Magento's internal cron as long as you have at least one cronjob setup for cron.php OR cron.sh then the internal cron will handle any scheduled tasks required.

Comment: [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job). On the bottom it says since version 1.4 "reindex all" is left out. What does that mean? The cron job won't reindex data? Should I add it back?

Comment: Consult the 1.9 code if you need more specifics as that is a pretty dated article: 2012.