# Magento 2: How to set cron for reindex in SSH in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, crontab, indexer

I want to know how to set cron for reindexing a particular indexer method in Magento 2. I have used below code to reindex all but not working:

```
* * * * * php –f /shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Can somebody help?

[image: my cronjob]

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84903/set-cron-for-reindex-specific-indexes http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50315/separate-cron-job-for-reindex-all can help? In Magento 2 `pub/cron.php`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can launch reindex a separate index as independent process, like:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /Users/uchuhlebov/web/m212/www/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product >> /Users/uchuhlebov/web/m212/www/var/log/indexer.cron.log
```

Where:

1. `* * * * *` - time
2. `/usr/bin/php` - path to the php
3. `/Users/uchuhlebov/web/m212/www/bin/magento` - path to your Magento **CLI** (`/Users/uchuhlebov/web/m212/www/` - is Magento root dir)
4. `indexer:reindex catalog_category_product` command you want to launch
5. `>> /Users/uchuhlebov/web/m212/www/var/log/indexer.cron.log` - log output

In my example I launch reindex of the `catalog_category_product` index, but you can use any type. If you want to launch more than 1 reindex, you can specify them ( index name ) through the space.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656678/how-to-get-path-of-the-php-binary-on-server-where-it-is-located)  you can find an answer for the question **"How to get path of the php binary on server"**:

> It's usually /usr/bin/php but you could try to capture and parse the
>   output of the command 'whereis php' or 'which php''.
>
> Or better yet, use the constant PHP_BINARY if it is available. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

In addition check that your [cron process is running](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-check-cronjob-is-running-not/): `/etc/init.d/crond status` should display something similar to `crond (pid  1494) is running...`

To view the list of available indexes use the command:

```
bin/magento indexer:info
```

Result:

```
design_config_grid                       Design Config Grid
customer_grid                            Customer Grid
catalog_category_product                 Category Products
catalog_product_category                 Product Categories
catalog_product_price                    Product Price
catalog_product_attribute                Product EAV
catalogsearch_fulltext                   Catalog Search
cataloginventory_stock                   Stock
catalogrule_rule                         Catalog Rule Product
catalogrule_product                      Catalog Product Rule
```

Comment: yet not working. Can my /usr/bin/php path be different on my server? or any solution?

Comment: @ArshadHussain Yes. Please look for the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656678/how-to-get-path-of-the-php-binary-on-server-where-it-is-located

Comment: @ArshadHussain In addition check that your cron process is running: `/etc/init.d/crond status` should display something similar to `crond (pid  1494) is running...`. Please, look at my updated answer.

Comment: which php gives "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php" and whereis php gives "php"

Comment: @ArshadHussain try to use `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php` in the cronjob

Comment: * * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento index:reindex catalog_product_price >> /apps/magento/htdocs/var/log/indexer.cron.log

Comment: neither log is creating nor it is working at all

Comment: @ArshadHussain Try `* * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price >> /apps/magento/htdocs/var/log/indexer.cron.log` : path to the magento should begin from `/` and process name is `indexer` (in your example it is `index`)

Comment: Please see my updated question (screenshot). Can you come on if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @ArshadHussain You are using incorrect path, try this: `* * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price >> /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/log/indexer.cron.log`. You can check whether the code works just executing it in the command line (without crons time-prefix * * * * * ) like `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price >> /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/log/indexer.cron.log`. As a result you should see error or log file in the magentos `var/log`

Comment: code is working and creating log file but if I put 5 star to set cron, it is not working?

Comment: @ArshadHussain That means that your cron process is not working. Try to run `ps aux | grep cron` and paste a result here.

Comment: I ran your command. Please see result in updated question (Screenshot below black image)

Comment: @ArshadHussain It is strange. Your cron is running, but your job isnt working :( May be here https://community.bitnami.com/t/problems-running-php-script-via-cron/8342/10 you can find some information.

Comment: But if I removed "/" from first path, it creates indexer.cron.log file with empty value but job does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/site/root/bin/magento index:reindex <index_type>
```

Comment: it is not working, is there any other keyword instead of "php"?

Comment: You may need /usr/bin/php.