# How to confirm that the reindex is working or not?

Tags: reindex, magento2.2.6

We have added a new product in one of the categories on our site using the Magento admin panel. But the added product is not visible in the frontend.

We have set the reindex mode to **Update on save** but still the product which we uploaded newly is not visible in the frontend.

Do I need to manually reindex the data every time whenever I add any new things on our site even though I set the index mode to Update on save?

Please reply with your thoughts.

I manually reindex the data using the below command but the **Product Categories** and **Catalog Product Rule** haven't been updated. Please refer the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You can set a cron job for running the indexer. Have a look at this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149408

Comment: Thanks for that. But, I want to know a clear view on what is the difference between Update on Save and Update by Schedule?. 
If I set the index mode to "Update on Save", it should reindex automatically when I have saved anything which is indexing data. So, what is the use of "Update by Schedule" here. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set indexes to Update on Save then you do not need to run reindex command manually every time. Check below points while creating a product:

1. Product is enabled.
2. Set Visibility of product to 'Catalog, search'.
3. Product is assigned to any category.
4. Product is in stock( Stock Status = In stock)
5. Product is assigned to any website.

**After creating product if any type of cache is enabled then flush cache.**

Comment: Thanks very much for this clarification. I have checked about the status of reindex in the index management via Magento admin panel. There I can see that the "Product categories" and "Catalog product rule" is not been updated eventhough I ran the command "php bin/magento indexer:reindex". In this case, how can i confirm that those indexers are working or not.

Comment: You can also check the status of each indexes by running below command:

**"php bin/magento indexer:status"**  

Are you trying to say that your all indexes are validated but still you are not able to see your changes?  

If yes then first run below command: 
 
**"php bin/magento indexer:reset"**  

and now:  

**"php bin/magento indexer:reindex"**  


Sometime this issue used to come in magento that all indexes are seems validated but still code is not reflected so in that situation we invalidate all indexes first and run reindex command again.

Comment: What should I do if I have to do the workflow which you mentioned all the times? Please see the attached screenshot in the question, there I have highlighted the indexers which haven't updated. It happens everytime. Please guide me.

Comment: You can create a shell file and update reset and reindex command in that file and add schedule a server cron for running that file.